# Using external .csv file in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to use an external .csv file with line-separated words to use in Google BigQuery.

I want to do something of this sort, please excuse the pseudocode:

```
import data_file
SELECT some_words FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare
WHERE some_words CONTAINS data_file.word
```

I want to do this for each word in the data file, iterating through every value. What is the relevant BigQuery syntax to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret your question as for every word in Shakespeare's work you want to find out if it exists in your CSV file. Once you uploaded your CSV file to BigQuery, you can use the following syntax in your SQL query:

```
SELECT word FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare
WHERE word IN (SELECT some_word FROM yourdataset.csvfile)
```

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is finding whether (word1 + " is " + word2) is in a google ngram, where word1 and word2 are found in the csv file, and return the ngram and its frequency. How do I do the concatenating part?

Comment: You concatenate with the "CONCAT" function. See BigQuery's reference at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference.

Comment: The two approaches are: 1. Cross join csv file table with itself, this will generate all the pairs, and concatenate them using CONCAT, and join with ngram. 2. Break ngram into components, and join each against csv file table.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use an external .csv file with line-separated words to use in Google BigQuery.

It is available now. Check https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources